# EE.com downloads of old versions corrupted

Tags: ee2, php7

I have an ancient site running EE 2.9.2. We're in the middle of a redesign, but it won't be ready before our host shuts off PHP 5.6 support. And PHP 7 support was added between 2.9.2 and 2.11.9.

I have two EE2 licenses on expressionengine.com, but when I download them, I get a 1 KB .zip file that doesn't open. Archive Utility chokes on it, BetterZip chokes on it, and I even downloaded WinZip for Mac, which says "End-of-central-directory signature not found." and then crashes.

Is this a known issue? Is there any way to get a working download of EE 2.11.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous versions of ExpressionEngine are available on Github:
https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine

See the guidance **If you're installing from the repository** but you should already have a *config.php* to use.

v2.11.9 is currently here:
https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/releases/tag/2.10.1

Comment: Hahaha, I already saw that, but disregarded it when I saw the 2.10.1 tag name. Thanks!